# Sending information in url parameters using XmlHttpRequest in get method, how do i retrieve those parameters in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest

I want to retrieve those two parameters which are passed in url
    
    
    
        // Read the text file with an XMLHttpRequest

```
    var xh;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xh = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert("Object created");
    }
    alert(xh);

    xh.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xh.readyState == 4 && xh.status == 200) {
            alert(xh.responseText);
            document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = xh.responseText;
        }
    }
    xh.open("GET", "Default.aspx?name=Henry&lname=Ford"", true);
    xh.send();

</script>
```

Now i want to retrieve those two parameters in aspx page.

Code in aspx page-

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(DateTime.Now);
}
}
```

Comment: This is not Classic ASP.  Please retag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get that using `QueryString` as GET  this is get request , params are passed using `QueryString`. For this url , you have to use following for in page_load to retrive.

> //Default.aspx?**name**=Henry&**lname**=Ford

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name,lname;
    if(Request.QueryString["name"]!=null)
        name = Request.QueryString["name"].ToString();
    if (Request.QueryString["lname"] != null)
        lname = Request.QueryString["lname"];
}
```

Comment: thanks but any other way to retrieve it?  I mean without using QueryString

Comment: Which way you are looking for? another way to get querystring - http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring

Comment: since you asked `how do i retrieve those parameters in aspx page?`, i have posted this, but why you want to use those param in external JS, as you are concerned how to get in `aspx`?

Comment: yeah...just a question. I will accept your answer ;)